# twitter block module

Tags: 8

I am trying to embed a timeline of tweets to my website's sidebar. I am using Drupal 8. The module "Twitter Block" requires a widget ID but Twitter has stopped providing widget ids and only generates html code but I don't know at which file should I embed this code to. Is there any other way? Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a big number in the HTML code? Big chance that is your ID.

Comment: It will work, just set your twitter id in the configuration

Comment: It works! A million thanks !It didn't require any Widget Id just the Twitter username. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this late reply... but here is the module you are looking for:

[Twitter API Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter_api_block)

As explained in its README file, you need to download it and the required library with composer, as follow:

```
composer require drupal/twitter_api_block drupal/j7mbo/twitter-api-php
```

Then go [create a new app in Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps) and finally, place the block in your Drupal site.

Simple :) Enjoy!